# how can i add single firebase node into listview?

Tags: android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to add name node in the list view, how can I add a single fireplace node into listview? I tried several things but unable to do it please anyone tell me how to do this, this is my code I am getting error in 
txt_one. setText(tecnames); it says that it should be char

this is my firebase database:
[image: this is my firebase database]

code

```
public class Technician extends Activity {
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
    ListView listView;
    ArrayList<String> tecnames = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_technician);
        ImageButton Back_Btn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.back);
        Back_Btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Technician.this, Skills.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        });
        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("user").child("name");
        myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                // This method is called once with the initial value and again
                // whenever data at this location is updated.
                String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                Pojo pojo=new Pojo();
                tecnames.add(pojo.getName(value));
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                // Failed to read value
                Log.w(TAG, "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
            }
        });


        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_item);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {


                Intent intent = new Intent(Technician.this, Book_Now.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });

        Technician.CostumAdapter costumAdapter = new Technician.CostumAdapter();
        listView.setAdapter(costumAdapter);

    }
}
```

this is my BaseAdapter

```
private class CostumAdapter extends BaseAdapter {


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return tecnames.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.cuctom_listview, null);
        TextView txt_one = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.skill_txt);
        txt_one.setText(tecnames);
        return view;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you attach your listener with `database.getReference("user").child("name")`, it attaches a listener to `/user/name`. And from the screenshot you shared, that location doesn't exist.

If you know the UID of the user you want to listen to, you can attach a listener with:

```
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("user").child(uid).child("name");
myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
```

Or shorter:

```
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("user/"+uid+"/name");
myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
```

On the other hand, if you don't know the UID, you will have to listen to the entire `/user` node and then navigate to the correct user and its `name` property in the `onDataChange` callback:

```
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("user");
myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String value = childSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            Pojo pojo=new Pojo();
            tecnames.add(pojo.getName(value));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
        // Failed to read value
        Log.w(TAG, "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
    }
});
```

That loop over `dataSnapshot.getChildren()` is needed, because there may be multiple users under `/user`. In that case the snapshot contains a list of those user nodes.

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Can't pass null for argument 'pathString' in child() at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.child(Unknown Source)

Comment: As the exception says, you're passing `null` into a `child()` call.  I don't see any call that can cause that in the code you shared or in what I posted, so it's likely coming from elsewhere. I recommend running in a debugger and seeing what line causes the problem.

Comment: i am showing outh user name to non outh users do you think this is the reason it is empty